# how to install pg_background extension in postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql

I want execute atomic transaction in PostgreSQL, I found this "https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background" link but could not understand the process, can any one explain how to do this installation on a Linux server?

Comment: They do have [installation steps](https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background#installation-steps) on the Readme on that github. What about those are unclear? or do you get any errors when you're attempting to do them?

Answer (score 1):

```
# yum install postgresql12-devel
# yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel \
  openssl-devel zlib-devel
# git clone https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background.git
# export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-12/bin
# cd /pg_background
# make
# make install
# sudo -iu postgres psql
postgres # CREATE EXTENSION pg_background;
```

Comment: How do i do it in windows 10 , postgres version 13?
The above steps are giving me an error!
@Valeh Ağayev